# How to enable sanitizers in QMake?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake, sanitizer

How do I enable usage of sanitizers in QMake's `.pro` files?

I found several ressources that modify `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` themselves but the [introductory blogpost](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/04/17/using-gccs-4-8-0-address-sanitizer-with-qt/) says:

> It is scheduled for the dev branch (Qt 5.2) because it’s a new feature, but you should be fine cherry-picking it to e.g. Qt 5.0. You can then configure Qt with -address-sanitizer, and run qmake CONFIG+=address_sanitizer for your own applications.

However, adding `CONFIG+=address_sanitizer` does not seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To enable, e.g., address sanitizer you have to write:

```
CONFIG += sanitizer sanitize_address
```

The sanitizer options are defined in Qt's mkspecs (`mkspecs/features/sanitizer.prf` and `mkspecs/common/sanitize.conf`), which gets loaded when you add `CONFIG += sanitizer`.
A quick look into my `sanitizer.prf` (Qt 5.7.0) shows that the specific sanitizers are:

- `sanitize_address`
- `sanitize_memory`
- `sanitize_thread`
- `sanitize_undefined`

Comment: The exact string I had to add is `CONFIG+=sanitizer CONFIG+=sanitize_address`.